# Help translate お人好しでおっちょこちょいな奴が絡んでいたというだけさ?

Tags: translation, word-usage

> 姫子「私としては、月見桐奈が納得する解釈を得られたらそれでよいと思っていたんだがな」
>
> 姫子「あいつは原作者によく質問をして『答え』を自ら考えようとしなかった」
>
> 姫子「だが、これで自分なりにキャラクターの解釈をまとめあげるということを覚えただろう」
>
> 寿季「先生は月見坂さんの成長を促したかったと？」
>
> 姫子「そんなところだ」
>
> 姫子「とはいえ、私から言い出したことではないんだがな」
>
> 寿季「え？」
>
> 姫子「**お人好しでおっちょこちょいな奴が絡んでいたというだけさ**」

Context: 月見坂桐葉 (i.e 月見桐奈) works as a 声優 who has recently dubbed for a heroine named 朱莉 in an anime. But her performance has been criticized by her teacher called 姫子, who is the author of a light novel from which the anime is adapted. The protagnist 寿季 is helping 桐葉 understand the act of 朱莉 in the novel. And, after reaching his conclusion, 寿季 arranges to meet 姫子 somewhere at the school to check his answer with the teacher.

What does the bold sentence mean? Can I translate it as "You were just mixing with a good-natured and clumsy person"?

Comment: お人好しでおっちょこちょいな奴 is the subject of the sentence as it is marked with が, not と.

Answer (score 3):

Going by the context you've provided here, we can understand a couple things in this text:

1. 姫子, as you explain, is a teacher/mentor to 月見坂桐葉/月見桐奈. And she speaks in a self-assured and patronizing manner.
2. who お人好しでおっちょこちょいな奴 refers to seems unclear. It could be someone else, or as @naruto points out, it could also be 姫子 or 寿季.
3. 言い出したこと means "idea" or "suggestion". 私から言い出したことではない: "wasn't my idea"

In smooth, conversational English, the second half goes something like this:

> 寿季: So you are saying (you did that because) you wanted to help her (月見坂桐葉/月見桐奈) grow?
>
> 姫子: Well, yeah, something like that. It wasn't my idea though.
>
> 寿季: Eh? What do you mean?
>
> 姫子: It's just, um, a good-hearted but scatterbrained someone has been involved, you know? (implying that someone good-hearted but scatterbrained has been helping 月見坂桐葉/月見桐奈)

Comment: I cannot determine who this "good-hearted but scatterbrained someone" refers to from this excerpt alone... It could be 姫子 or somebody else unmentioned in this excerpt, but I think it could even be 寿季.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it turned out to Himeko herself. She clearly said 私から言い出したことではない. She would have to be schizophrenic or something. But this is something the OP can find out by continuing reading.

Comment: @aguijonazo "schizophrenic".. hahaha. I thought this was 姫子 trying to let on about a mysterious character... but after reading naruto's comment, I guess 寿季 can also be a possible referent?